# Using query in async function

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

I want to add an option to use a query to search for certain strings in a tweets stream.
I want to switch the 'coding' string in the code for a query I get from the URL.
How can I do that?

```
let nowTweets = (cb) => {
    T.get('search/tweets', { q: 'coding', count: 10 }, function (err, data,response) {
        const tweets = data.statuses
        .map(tweet => tweet.text)
        console.log(tweets);
        cb(tweets)
    })
}

app.get('/tweets', (req, res) => {
    nowTweets(tweets => {
        res.send('Tweets: ' + '\n' + tweets)
    })
})
```

Comment: Just pass a query argument into `nowTweets`. You're already passing in a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like `req.params` or `req.query` to get your search string from the url of your route and pass it it as argument to your `nowTweets()`

For express:
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.params
https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query